# how to increase default zoom/magnification for the matlab documentation

Tags: matlab, application-settings

Every time I go into MATLAB documentation I have to increase the zoom with  <kbd>^</kbd>  +  <kbd>+</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>+</kbd>

as the writing is tiny.

How do I change the default zoom?
Alternative workarounds welcome.

OS X -   MATLAB_2015a

Comment: You should be able to customize this in Preferences > Fonts > Custom (by selecting a larger font size for the help).

Comment: @CST-Link No, under help browser font, it says to use 'Zoom In' or 'Zoom Out'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to do this from the UI. However, since the help files are HTML and make use of CSS, you can edit a stylesheet in the MATLAB package. I found this to work: Right-click on the MATLAB application package and choose 'Show Package Contents'. Then, navigate to `help/includes/product/css` and open `doc_center.css` in a text editor. Add the line

```
body { zoom: 1.3; }
```

near the top. Change the current page in the doc viewer and adjust the zoom level as desired.